# Returning data from server method to client after server calls an HTTP API

Tags: meteor

I am trying to learn Meteor, starting by writing a simple application where the server calls an HTTP API based on user input, processes the information, then returns it to the client to display it.

I am not having much success. I can't seem to return the result from server to client:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    checkTransit: function(method, url, options) {
      this.unblock();
      return Meteor.http.call(method, url, function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
          console.log('SERVER ERRR');
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('SERVER RESULT');
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
    }
  })
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {

   Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function(event) {
     // Prevent default browser form submit
     event.preventDefault();

     var text = event.target.text.value;

     var method = 'GET';
     var url = 'http://sometransitapi.com';
     var options = {
       headers: {
         'accept': 'application/XML',
         'content-type': 'application/XML'
       }
     }

     Meteor.call('checkTransit', method, url, options, function (error, result) {

       if (error) {
          console.log('CLIENT ERRR');
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('CLIENT RESULT');

          var parser;
          parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlDoc
          xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/xml");

          console.log(xmlDoc);
        }
     })

   }
 })
}
```

I can see the results being returned to the result variable at isServer, but I can not pass the result to the xmlDoc variable in isClient. What am I doing wrong? Is this the correct way to structure things for what I want to do in Meteor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Meteor.http.call` is being called asynchronously in your server code (you are passing a callback). The functions in your `Meteor.methods` object expect to return a value, so you should be calling `Meteor.http.call` synchronously. Changing your server code to below should do the trick.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.methods({
    checkTransit: function(method, url, options) {
      this.unblock();
      // This will throw an exception and return it as the error object
      // in your Meteor.call if an error occurs, otherwise it will
      // return an empty error object and the result object will be
      // the return value from Meteor.http.call
      return Meteor.http.call(method, url);
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the logic on the server side then @Curtis' answer should help you.

Looking at what you have, I don't see much of a point of getting the server to do the work. The `Http` api is available everywhere in Meteor. You are just fetching data, which can be solely done on the front end. This would also technically make it faster. Taking your code and moving it around a bit you get the following.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
 Template.body.events({
   "submit .new-task": function(event) {
     // Prevent default browser form submit
     event.preventDefault();

     var text = event.target.text.value;

     var method = 'GET';
     var url = 'http://sometransitapi.com';
     var options = {
       headers: {
         'accept': 'application/XML',
         'content-type': 'application/XML'
       }
     }
     Http.call(method, url, options, function (error, result) {
       if (error) {
          console.log('CLIENT ERRR');
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          console.log('CLIENT RESULT');

          var parser;
          parser = new DOMParser();
          var xmlDoc
          xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(result, "text/xml");

          console.log(xmlDoc);
        }
     });
    }
 });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. In what situation would I do things on the server side? I thought it would make sense to pull the data and process it at the server side, but maybe I am misunderstanding the basics?

Comment: You would want to pull it server side if you want to store the data or a portion of the data or just keep track of it. Essentially if you want to reference back to that data in a persistent way bring it to the server and store what you need to store. If you don't care about it, and just pulling based on what the user wants and is discarded after the user is done with it, there is no need to pull to server.